# How to retrieve latest item from DynamoDB table (Java)

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, datastore

I am trying to create an IoT project where sensor data is sent every second to DynamoDB and an android app has to display it on the front-end. Using AWS Amplify, I was able to build an app that retrieves the data from the table with a button press according to its ID. What I want to retrieve is the latest item from the DB. I believe this can be done by sorting all the items in descending order and limiting the items to be retrieved by 1, and putting it in a loop.

My problem is I am having difficulty in writing the correct syntax for it. This is my current code:

```
    public void readById() {
        String objectId = "f5d470f6-72e2-49b6-bf28-43d7db130de4";

        Amplify.DataStore.query(
                MyModel.class,
                Where.id(objectId),
                items -> {

                    while (items.hasNext()) {
                        MyModel item = items.next();
                        retrievedItem = item.getName().toString();

                        Log.i("Amplify", "Id " + item.getId() + " " + item.getName());
                    }
                    
                },
                failure -> Log.e("Amplify", "Could not query DataStore", failure)
        );
    }
```

The code below is what I want to achieve, but trying this method did not work because I can't find the builder() method under QueryOptions or QueryPredicate even though my AWS amplify dependencies is up to date.

```
Amplify.DataStore.query(MyModel.class, QueryOptions.builder()
    .sort(MyModel.TIMESTAMP, SortOrder.DESCENDING)
    .limit(1)
    .build(),
    result -> {
        System.out.println(result.get(0));
    },
    error -> {
        System.out.println(error.getCause());
    });
```

I saw a code snippet from amplify docs (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/sync/q/platform/android/#reevaluate-expressions-at-runtime) about advanced use cases of Query but it does not seem to sync with my code, see image below:

```
Amplify.addPlugin(AWSDataStorePlugin.builder().dataStoreConfiguration(
    DataStoreConfiguration.builder()
        .syncExpression(User.class, () -> User.LAST_NAME.eq("Doe").and(User.CREATED_AT.gt("2020-10-10")))
        .build())
    .build());
```

I am new to AWS so it's a struggle but I'm willing to learn. Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Are you interested in using AMazon DyanamoDB with the AWS SDK for Java or this amplify JS script

Comment: @smac2020 Im using Amplify but in Java (for the arduino app im building)

Answer (score 0):

You're potential going to be sending and retrieving a lot of data from dynamodb. Could you cache the data locally when your app starts, then write the data to dynamodb before your program ends?

You could add ZonedDateTime.now() or similar, to record when each point of data is created? If you use Set setName, you could use something like setName.sort(Comparator.comparing(ClassName::getZonedDateTime))